# For loop with a list of arguments

Tags: javascript, qt, for-loop, qml, qtquick2

In Bash one can simply list the elements to iterate over:

```
for i in 1 7 45
do echo $i
done
```

Of course one could do

```
array = [1, 7, 45]
for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) console.log(array[i])
delete array
```

But this won't go, for example, in QML and is a little clumsy. One could simply leave the array but I'd rather avoid it. I'd like the array to be destroyed straight after executing the loop.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: You could use `for(let i of [1,7,45]){…}` or `[1,7,45].forEach(function(){…})`. Not sure about QML at all, though.

Comment: @Xufox the latter works in QML, the former not. Your comment is the best solution so far.

Comment: Ok, that means ECMAScript 6 `for-of` loops aren’t working there.

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
array = [1, 7, 45]
array.forEach( function(e){
  console.log(e);
});
```

**UPDATED**

If you don't want to create an array, you can do:

```
[1 ,7, 45].forEach(function(e){console.log(e);})
```

Comment: I don't want to create the `array` object.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
var array = [1, 7, 45]
for (var i in array) 
{
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/66fgx58x/

Comment: I don't want to create the `array` object.

Comment: Then you have to describe it better.

Comment: I'd like to do something like: `for (var i in [1,7,45])  { console.log( /*...*/) }`